# Bounding box collision between specific tiles and a sprite using vectors and multimap

Tags: c++, sdl, game-physics, sdl-2

I have a set of random x and y co-ordinate values generated and have stored them to a multimap and then have copied the list of x co-ordinate values to a vector x and the list of y co-ordinate values to a vector y and then have passed them in the function iteratively

```
bool Sprite::collisionExists( int x, int y, SDL_Rect b  )
```

and I pass it in my`checkCollisions()` function in an if statement like this

```
 collisionExists( x[k],y[l],sprite)
```

where sprite is the SDL_Rect type I created in that function.

I have a tile map created filled with rocks where I want the sprite to move around in the map but not being able to go forward if a rock is in the next tile.

The problem I am facing is that I can't seem to detect any collision when I created a vector and compared each value whereas before when it tested it with  only two images the code worked perfectly.

Here is the code where I randomly insert the x and y co-ordinate values for the tiled map

```
//randomly set positions of the rocks
void setRandomRockPositions()
{
for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
{
    int x,y;

    int minX=3;
    int maxX=8;
    x=roll(minX,maxX);


    int minY=1;
    int maxY=9;
    y=roll(minY,maxY);

    //if x and y are not the location for the house tile, add a rock
    if((x!=9 && y!=5))
    {
        rocks.insert(std::pair<int, int>(x, y));

    }
 }

}
```

Some variables and constant declarations

```
  //Screen attributes
const int SCREEN_WIDTH  = 1024;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 728;

// Scaling the tiles to be 80x80
const int TILE_SIZE = 80;

std::multimap<int, int> rocks;
static const int SPRITE_WIDTH = 104;
static const int SPRITE_HEIGHT = 96;
```

The code for detecting collision between the sprite and rocks

```
bool Sprite::checkCollisions()
{
SDL_Rect sprite;
sprite.x= mPosX;
sprite.y=mPosY;
sprite.w=SPRITE_WIDTH;
sprite.h=SPRITE_HEIGHT;

std::vector<int> x(rocks.size());
std::vector<int> y(rocks.size());

std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it=rocks.begin();

while(it!=rocks.end())
{
    for(int i=0;i<rocks.size();i++)
    {
        x[i]= (*it).first;
        ++it;
    }
}

std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it2=rocks.begin();
while(it2!=rocks.end())
{
    for(int j=0;j<rocks.size();j++)
    {
        y[j]=(*it2).second;
        ++it2;
    }
}

for(int k=0;k<rocks.size();k++)
{
    for(int l=0; l<rocks.size();l++)
    {
        if(collisionExists( x[k],y[l],sprite))
        {
            return true;
            std::cout<<"Collision Detected!"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

The basic detection collision code

```
bool Sprite::collisionExists( int x, int y, SDL_Rect b  )
{
//The sides of the rectangles
int leftA, leftB;
int rightA, rightB;
int topA, topB;
int bottomA, bottomB;

//Calculate the sides of rect A
leftA = x;
rightA = x + SPRITE_WIDTH;
topA = y;
bottomA = y + SPRITE_HEIGHT;

//Calculate the sides of rect B
leftB = b.x;
rightB = b.x + b.w;
topB = b.y;
bottomB = b.y + b.h;

//If any of the sides from A are outside of B
if( bottomA <= topB)//-50 )
{
    return false;
}

if( topA >= bottomB)//-50 )
{
    return false;
}

if( rightA <= leftB)//+50 )
{
    return false;
}

if( leftA >= rightB)//-50 )
{
    return false;
}

//If none of the sides from A are outside B
return true;
}
```

I think my problem lies in the `checkCollisions()` function, because the the ouput "Collision Detected" is never shown on the console. I have tried many variations of looping and storing them from the map to the vector but I still can't figure out why the collision detection stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've realised now is actually very simple. I had to multiply each element of x and y with the tile size.

`collisionExists( x[k]*TILE_SIZE,y[l]*TILE_SIZE,sprite)`

I was passing x and y co-ordinates instead to my function and that was a fundamental error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

> I think my problem lies in the checkCollisions() function, because the the ouput "Collision Detected" is never shown on the console.

That might be due to the fact that `checkCollisions()` returns before displaying the "Collision Detected!" message. Move the `return` one line lower, and it might work as expected:

```
if(collisionExists( x[k],y[l],sprite))
{
    std::cout << "Collision Detected!" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

Try it.

---

By the way, you might want to

- switch from global variables to (const) reference parameters
- simply step through your `rocks` container instead of using two loops to fill separate x and y vectors, where you then test every x coordinate against every y coordinate.

  ```
  for( const auto & coords : rocks ) {
      if( collisionExists( coords.first, coords.seconds, sprite) ) {
          std::cout << "Collision Detected!" << std::endl;
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- if you really want to use each x with each y, you could at least fill the separate vectors in a single loop:

  ```
  for( const auto & coords : rocks ) {
      x.push_back( coords.first );
      y.push_back( corrds.second );
  }
  ```

*(Warning: all code written in browser only -- uncompiled and untested!)*

Comment: Yeah you're right, somehow I completely failed to notice that, but now after swapping the two lines of code I get 4 messages to my console saying "Collision Detected" before I even start moving the player and I am still moving through rocks so there is probably some logical error I can't see yet. And also, I did not know I could do that. "rocks" is a multimap and I thought I could only access it through an iterator. I didn't know I could do it by reference and dot notation.

Comment: I actually didn't know about 'const auto' and was calling it as referencing and dot notation before but I did a bit of search and it makes more sense now. Although I still don't understand why you used 'const auto & coords' and did not access the 'multimap<int,int> rocks' through iterators.

Comment: The `for( elem : container )` is a range-for that's new in C++11, and you can add secondary attributes like `const`, or `&` for references. Writing `for( const & elem : container )` instead of `for( container_type::const_iterator iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter )` neatly shows that you want to do something with every `elem`ent in the `container`, but without changing any of them.

Comment: Additional reading: [the entry in Bjarne Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto), and [Herb Sutter dealing with some `auto` pitfalls](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-92-auto-variables-part-1/).